# Wordpress: Issue when going to page/2/ of the Search with Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, search, pagination

Trying to apply a better pagination for my Wordpress and I found this code that adds a pagination to a WP_Query somewhere here in stackoverflow. So I edited my codes from just having have_posts(), then included that WP_Query to add the filter and paged*. The code below works fine on a custom template where category = music and the pagination works fine too.

```
       <?php
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $data= new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'=>'post',
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'category_name' => 'music',
    ));
    if($data->have_posts()) :
        while($data->have_posts())  : $data->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        
    <div>
        <?php
        $total_pages = $data->max_num_pages;

        if ($total_pages > 1){
    
            $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                'format' => '/page/%#%',
                'current' => $current_page,
                'total' => $total_pages,
                'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
                'next_text'    => __('next »'),
            ));
        }
        ?> 
    </div>

        <?php
        else :
                echo '<p>No content found</p>';
        
    endif; 
    ?> <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Now for the code in my search.php :
The only difference is that the one above uses category_name, which the search uses the $s parameter. It works on the first page, but when I click the page 2, it doesn't search anything and instead shows the first page again and some added text in the Url. I feel that it shouldn't be this case because I already have a queried result but Idk.

```
<?php
    
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $s = get_search_query();

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged,
        's' => $s
    );

    $data = new WP_Query($args);

    if($data->have_posts()) :
        while($data->have_posts())  : $data->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        
    <div>
        <?php
        $total_pages = $data->max_num_pages;

        if ($total_pages > 1){
    
            $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
    
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                'format' => '/page/%#%',
                'current' => $current_page,
                'total' => $total_pages,
                'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
                'next_text'    => __('next »'),
            ));
        }
        ?> 
    </div>

        <?php
        else :
                echo '<p>No content found</p>';
        
    endif; 
    ?> <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

I appreciate any help regarding this issue, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **search.php**:

```
<?php
    
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
    $s = get_search_query();

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'paged' => $paged,
        's' => $s
    );

    $data = new WP_Query($args);
    //print_r($data);
    if($data->have_posts()) :
        while($data->have_posts())  : $data->the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part('content', get_post_format()); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        
    <div>
        <?php
        $total_pages = $data->max_num_pages;

        if ($total_pages > 1){
    
            $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('page'));
    
            echo paginate_links(array(
                'base' => @add_query_arg('page','%#%'),
                'format' => '?page=%#%',
                'current' => $current_page,
                'total' => $total_pages,
                'prev_text'    => __('« prev'),
                'next_text'    => __('next »'),
            ));
        }
        ?> 
    </div>

        <?php
        else :
                echo '<p>No content found</p>';
        
    endif; 
    ?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I actually have the code on my search.php. Please look at the 3rd line.

Comment: Ok, i tried your code, will edit my answer

Comment: @BryanWill try this

Comment: Okay, that solved it. I noticed that you removed the "d" from paged, and changed the args for 'base'. Can you explain a little why?

Also, thank you so much!

Comment: The search URL in WordPress is built using the GET parameter 's', therefore, pagination must be passed in the get parameter (for this, the arguments of the paginate_links function have been changed). Changing the parameter from 'paged' in 'page' is due to the fact that 'paged' is reserved for WordPress and if you left it you will throw 404 error

Comment: Oh I see. Great information, thanks once again!